# Github action's output: How can I set an output var in a composite file

Tags: bash, environment-variables, output, github-actions

I am trying to understand where is my mistake:
I want to set an output var in a composite file but I keep getting an empty result:

`'Output - ${{ steps.hello-world.outputs.random-number }}'` returns `'Output - '`
Like `'${{ steps.hello-world.outputs.random-number }}'` is never set.

main-workflow.yml:

```
name: My action 

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    
jobs:
  test-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    steps:
      - name: Call Hello World 
        id: hello-world
        uses: actions/hello-world-action@v1
      - name: Comment
        run: echo 'Output - ${{ steps.hello-world.outputs.random-number }}'
```

The file in which I want to set the variable:

```
name: 'Hello World'
description: 'Greet someone'
inputs:
  who-to-greet:  # id of input
    description: 'Who to greet'
    required: false
    default: 'World'
outputs:
  random-number:
    description: "Random number"
    value: ${{ steps.random-number-generator.outputs.random-number }}
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - name: Random number generator
      id: random-number-generator
      run: "random-number=$(echo 123)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      shell: bash
```

Comment: You almost had it: instead of `"random-number=$(echo 123)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT`, it should be `echo "random-number=123" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT`.

Comment: Do you have a link to the workflow run?

Comment: Please
https://github.com/davseve/davtest1/actions/runs/5786026101/job/15679896084

Comment: I think you won't have access..

Comment: I don't :) If you can make the repo public, I'm happy to take a look.

Comment: Please try again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254838/discussion-between-davsev-and-benjamin-w).

Comment: You're referencing actions/hello-world-action, which redirects to the GitHub-made https://github.com/actions/hello-world-javascript-action. To use your own action, use `uses: davseve/davtest1/.github/workflows/hello-world-action@main`, or (since you're in the same repository), with a relative path `uses: ./.github/workflows/hello-world-action`. Usually, the `action.yml` is in the top-level directory of a repo.

Comment: Thanks!
Do I need to run `actions/checkout` before running the local action?

Comment: When using a relative reference, then yes, you have to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that more people will come across the same issue as I did.

This is my final code:

main-workflow.yml:

```
name: My action 

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    
jobs:
  test-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Call Hello World 
        id: hello-world
        uses: ./.github/workflows/hello-world-action
      - name: Comment
        run: echo 'Output - ${{ steps.hello-world.outputs.random-number }}'
      - name: Composite Check
        uses: ./.github/workflows/read-output
        with: 
          rand: ${{ steps.hello-world.outputs.random-number }}
```

hello-world-action.yml:

Let's take this example composite action found on Github's documentation:

```
name: 'Hello World'
description: 'Greet someone'
inputs:
  who-to-greet:  # id of input
    description: 'Who to greet'
    required: false
    default: 'World'
outputs:
  random-number:
    description: "Random number"
    value: ${{ steps.random-number-generator.outputs.random-number }}
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - name: Random number generator
      id: random-number-generator
      run: |
        test=1234
        echo "random-number=$test" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      shell: bash
```